# Apache rewrite all incoming to same address

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Hi I want to direct all traffic on port 443 to teh same adress but I want to kepp the parameters.

I have tried to read how to do it and right now I have something like this

```
<Virtualhost x.x.x.x:443>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^(.*)example2.com/test/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example1.example2.com/test/$1 [R,L]
```

So basically I want to rewrite everything that doesn't have example2.com/test/ in the URI

Example if I get `www.example.com?parameter=5`
I want it to be `https://example1.example2.com/test?parameter=5`

Answer (score 0):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` is *only the URI* and not the hostname. So there will never be `example.com` in the variable, and thus the condition will always be true (unless you're actually going to `http://example1.example2.com/example2.com/test/`).

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example1.example2.com/test%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```